# Book where Earth-descended colonies were fighting for independence from tyrannical Earth

Tags: story-identification, books

I can't remember the author or title of a book. The main characters were called 'Absolute' (actual name) and 'Loverboy' (derogatory nickname).

Plot was roughly Earth-based tyranny and colonies striking for independence.
Earth developed tech to force humans into a plasma state to be ultimate weapons. Absolute and Loverboy were both colonials trying for freedom and then to spearhead independence fight.

I had it as a paperback, I think DAW, before 2005.